# Average of BYROW and BYCOL results in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, average

I have a `20x20` table for which I applied the `BYROW` and `BYCOL` functions to get the row totals and column totals.

Function 1:

```
B22=BYROW(B2:U21,LAMBDA(row,SUM(row)))
```

Function 2:

```
V2=BYCOL(B2:U21,LAMBDA(column,SUM(column)))
```

How can I achieve the following steps?

1. I want to find the average of Row 1 total and Column 1 total and repeat this for all rows and columns resulting in an array of 20 values.
2. I want to use `LARGE(Array, k)` function to find the top 10 values of the values stored in the array in step 1.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but is this what you are looking for? =LARGE(BYROW(HSTACK(TOCOL(BYCOL(B2:U21,LAMBDA(column,SUM(column)))),BYROW(B2:U21,LAMBDA(row,SUM(row)))),LAMBDA(x,AVERAGE(x))),SEQUENCE(10,1,1,1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put them all together:

```
=TAKE(SORT(BYROW(HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(B22#),V2#),LAMBDA(RW,AVERAGE(RW))),1,-1),10)
```

[image]

---

As stated by @user11222393, to get the row/column from where the value comes:

```
=TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(BYROW(HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(B22#),V2#),LAMBDA(RW,AVERAGE(RW))),SEQUENCE(COUNT(B22#),1,1,1)),1,-1),10)
```

Since relative row and relative column number are the same it will return a single relative number.

[image]

---

If you want it a little prettier:

```
=TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(BYROW(HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(B22#),V2#),LAMBDA(RW,AVERAGE(RW))),LET(r,SEQUENCE(COUNT(B22#),1,2,1),"CLM: "&CHAR(65+r)&" rw: "&r)),1,-1),10)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way we can find the corresponding row index and column index to each of these top 10 values

Comment: By index you mean index of sheet position or your table B2:U21? If the latter this might work =TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(BYROW(HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(B22#),V2#),LAMBDA(RW,AVERAGE(RW))),SEQUENCE(COUNT(B22#),1,1,1)),1,-1),10)  and in this case row index = column index

Comment: I mean to find which row and column resulted in high average of totals.

Comment: I keep getting errors with the above formula may be the brackets are inconsistent.

Comment: @vp_050 They all work for me.  What errors are you getting? is your data similar to what I show?

Comment: This error keeps popping "There's a problem with this formula". Not sure where to start.

Comment: I misplaced the brackets in my formula.